# Apache Storm Flux change topology

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-flux

Is it possible to change the topology layout while it is running? I would like to change the stream groupings and bolts while it is active.

Submitting the yaml file with the new topology layout says it cannot deploy since it is already running.

I'm using Apache Storm 0.10.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the structure of a topology while it is running. You need to `kill` the topology and redeploy the new version afterwards.

The only parameter you can change while a topology is running it the parallelism. See here for more details:

V 2.0.0 - https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html